# How to initialize a new Camera.Size in Android

Tags: android

For example:

```
int width = 720;
int height = 1280;
```

I want to create a Camera.Size.

```
Camera.Size size = new Camera.Size(width,height);
```

But it has some error.

```
No enclosing instance of type Camera is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type Camera (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of Camera).
```

Answer (score 19):

Actually, a slightly different syntax is required:

```
Camera camera = Camera.open();
Camera.Size size = camera.new Size(width, height);
```

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks a lot! I didn't know that I need to use camera.new. Awesome!

Answer (score 9):

I know you have posted your question a long time ago but I have some explanation about this error. As you can see [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.3_r1/android/hardware/Camera.java#Camera.Size) the class Size is declared as public (but non static) into the class Camera. You can find some information about this architecture [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html).

So to create a new Camera.Size object, you have to start by creating a Camera object.

```
Camera camera = Camera.open();
```

Then you can create your Camera.Size object:

```
Camera.Size size = camera.new Camera.Size(width, height);
```

I'm not sure you really want to use this way to do this, but this is the explanation about your error.